# Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference - Perl Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious, hashref

So I'm a bit of a noob at Perl but in essence this code is part of my model (inserting into an SQL database).

The error I'm getting when running this code is

> Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference

I think the clear solution to this is to define a hash containing a key called "host_id".

How would I go about that or fixing my code?

```
    ####delete subfunctions
    ######
    sub deletehostservices
    {
      my ($self, $host_service_id) = @_;

      my $host_id = $self->pg->db->query('DELETE from hosts_services where hosts_services_id = ? returning host_id', $host_service_id)->hash->{host_id};
      return $host_id;
    }
```

Comment: Does the `query` method return something that has a `hash` method? You need to consult your documentation. Could also be that your SQL is incorrect. Do you see any error messages from the database?

Comment: The query method works fine in other instances, I believe it is the declaring the host_id assignment as part of a hash that is causing the errors here.

Comment: Use Data::Printer to dump out the return value of the query method first. If that doesn't help, look at the return value of the hash method. The error you get refers to the final part of your chain of arrows. The method hash returns undef and you try to access that like a hash ref.

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct? ( a hash key should be wrapped with curly brackets; e.g. `$hash->{key}->{another_key}->{and_another_key}`)

Comment: The second thing you can do is to check the value of `$host_service_id`. You can print it to see it's value with this code : `use Data::Dumper;` `print Dumper $host_service_id;`. My assumption is that you are calling the function `deletehostservices` with an undefined value.

Comment: The reason is clearly that `hash` is returning `undef`, however it is hard to say *why* that is happening without a lot more information. What class is `$self`? Is it from a CPAN module or have you written it yourself? You need to check whether a database operation succeeded before you go ahead and use its results.

Comment: I can tell that you are using Mojo::Pg and it is being used correctly. The only thing that would help answer the question is to tell us where this function is coming from. Is it from a controller or a helper?

Comment: The code is incomplete, and most of all the error depends on the first value (`$self`) passed to `deletehostservices`.

Answer (score 0):

When Mojo::Pg's `->hash` method returns undef it is because no rows were returned.

You could store your result in a temporary variable with a default

```
my $res = $self->pg->db->query(
  'DELETE from hosts_services where hosts_services_id = ? returning host_id', $host_service_id
)->hash || {};
return $res->{host_id};
```

or any of several other patterns to handle getting undef. The above is the one I like in this kind of case though.